# Relating nodes in csv with column names in Neo4J

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a csv file in below format,
[image: ![enter image description here]

1. There are **n** location columns of various locations.
2. There's **Token** column at the end where each location row is associated with a different token.

### TASK

Associate each token to each location column such that the relationship is named after the column name.

### Example

[image]

### My cypher code

```
load csv with headers from "file:///locations.csv" as row with row where row is not null
merge (l1:locations {name:row.LOC_1})
merge (t:tokens {name:row.Token})
merge (l1) -[:LOC_1]->(t)
```

As you can see, This code loads each column and relates them to tokens manually which is a tedious task. In reality, there are 67 columns and doing this manually takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create relationship types dynamically, you will need the [apoc](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.relationship/) library. And a bit of [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension). That allows you to do this:

```
load csv with headers from "file:///locations.csv" AS row 
with row where row is not null

// create an array of maps, using the keys() function
with row.Token AS token,
     [key IN keys(row) WHERE key<>'Token' | {relType:key,location:row[key]}] as relTypeLocs
unwind relTypeLocs AS relTypeLoc
merge (l:locations {name:COALESCE(relTypeLoc.location,'Unknown')})
merge (t:tokens {name:token})
WITH l,t,
     relTypeLoc.relType AS relType
// use apoc to create the rels
CALL apoc.create.relationship(t,relType,{}, l) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

To remove the 'Unknown':

```
MATCH (l:locations {name:'Unknown'})
DETACH DELETE l
```

That said, two things to consider:

- you can also set the LOC_1 .. LOC_N as a property on the relationship. Then you can do this in pure cypher.
- You use plurals for the node labels. Since labels are kind of tags, consider using the singular.

Comment: The original columns are in this form, `c1...cn`. What should I change in the code to make it work? Also, there are some null values in some columns, how to avoid them and fill all non-null values?

Comment: `Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'name': (:locations {name: null})`

Comment: @Dagad well, you have to have a way of distinguishing the column in which you have the token. The easiest way would be to rename the header for that column to  'Token' .

Comment: you can use COALESCE() to deal with the empty values. And delete the Unknown nodes afterwards. see expanded answer.

Comment: Started running the code. There are more than 1.5Lakh records and 67 columns, so it's taking time. In the meantime, can you please explain the code minimally?

Comment: Don't know how many 1.5Lakh is in decimals ;)  What the code basically does is work towards a list of token,location,relType .  Besides the functions I provided links for, please look at keys(), coalesce() , UNWIND which are all quite well documented in Neo4j's Cypher manuals.

Comment: Oh okay. 1.5 Lakhs = 150,000 and it's still running 

Comment: That’s too long. With indexes and constraints set it should be done in less than a minute

Comment: I don't know. Can you modify the code, such that it'd run faster? (It's still running since an hour)

Comment: It’s not in the cypher statement. Please read the Neo4j documentation about index and constraints.